# Regex to pull out numbers and operands

Tags: regex, python-3.6

I am trying to write a regex to parse out seven match objects:  four numbers and three operands:

Individual lines in the file look like this:

```
[  9]  -21 - ( 12) - (  -5) + ( -26) = ______
```

The number in brackets is the line number which will be ignored.  I want the four integer values, (including the '-' if it is a negative integer), which in this case are -21, 12, -5 and -26.  I also want the operands, which are -, - and +.

I will then take those values (match objects) and actually compute the answer:

```
-21 - 12 - -5 + -26 = -54
```

I have this:

```
[\s+0-9](-?[0-9]+)
```

In Pythex it grabs the [  9] but it also then grabs every integer in separate match objects (four additional match objects). I don't know why it does that.

If I add a ? to the end: `[\s+0-9](-?[0-9]+)?`  thinking it will only grab the first integer, it doesn't.  I get seventeen matches?

I am trying to say, via the regex: Grab the line number and it's brackets (that part works), then grab the first integer including sign, then the operand, then the next integer including sign, then the next operand, etc.

---

It appears that I have failed to explain myself clearly.

The file has hundreds of lines.  Here is a five line sample:

```
[  1]   19 - (   1) - (   4) + (  28) = ______
[  2]  -18 + (   8) - (  16) - (   2) = ______
[  3]   -8 + (  17) - (  15) + ( -29) = ______
[  4]  -31 - ( -12) - (  -5) + ( -26) = ______
[  5]  -15 - (  12) - (  14) - (  31) = ______
```

The operands are only '-' or '+', but any combination of those three may appear in a line.  The integers will all be from -99 to 99, but that shouldn't matter if the regex works.  The goal (as I see it) is to extract seven match objects:  four integers and three operands, then add the numbers 
exactly as they appear.  The number in brackets is just the line number and plays no role in the computation.

Comment: Wait so you want to retrieve the line number or not? Since you're not just grabbing the numbers but the operands as well, it sounds like you just want to split your string on spaces.

Comment: [mcve] seen? Please show a clear literal initialisation, your code, preferably an example, which we can cut'n'paste into our python terminal. Sample input, expected output, working code (which doesn't segfault or such).

Comment: I am grabbing the line number just to get it out of the way.  I want the integers and the operands so I can then compute the sum of the numbers.  I am using Pythex to work through the logic of the Regex but I am stuck.  I posted what I have and what it is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh...   I had a cup of coffee and sat down in front of Pythex again.

I figured out the correct regex:

```
[\s+0-9]\s+(-?[0-9]+)\s+([-|+])\s+\(\s+(-?[0-9]+)\)\s+([-|+])\s+\(\s+(-?[0-9]+)\)\s+([-|+])\s+\(\s+(-?[0-9]+)\)
```

Yields:

1. -21
2. -
3. 12
4. -
5. -5
6. +
7. -26

Answer (score 1):

Much luck with regex, if you just need the result:

```
import re

s="[  9]  -21 - ( 12) - (  -5) + ( -26) = ______"

s = s[s.find("]")+1:s.find("=")]           #  cut away line nr and = ...

if not re.sub( "[+-0123456789() ]*","",s): #  weak attempt to prevent python code injection
    print(eval(s))
else:
    print("wonky chars inside, only numbers, +, - , space and () allowed.")
```

Output:

```
-54
```

Make sure to read the [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) 
and have a look into:

- https://opensourcehacker.com/2014/10/29/safe-evaluation-of-math-expressions-in-pure-python/
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311507/why-are-eval-like-features-considered-evil-in-contrast-to-other-possibly-harmfu/311510
- https://www.kevinlondon.com/2015/07/26/dangerous-python-functions.html

---

Example for *hundreds of lines*:

```
import re

s="[  9]  -21 - ( 12) - (  -5) + ( -26) = ______"


def calcIt(line):
    s = line[line.find("]")+1:line.find("=")] 

    if not re.sub( "[+-0123456789() ]*","",s):
        return(eval(s))
    else:
        print(line + " has wonky chars inside, only numbers, +, - , space and () allowed.")
        return None


import random
random.seed(42)

pattern = "[ {}]  -{} - ( {}) - (  -{}) + ( -{}) = "


for n in range(1000):
    nums = [n]
    nums.extend([ random.randint(0,100),random.randint(-100,100),random.randint(-100,100),
                  random.randint(-100,100)])
    c = pattern.format(*nums)
    print (c, calcIt(c))
```

Comment: Sorry, there are hundreds of lines.  I need to read each one and pull out the data, not just that one line.

Comment: @MarkS Now it does a thousand lines, thats enough? Just fetch the lines from your file and put them through `calcIt` ...